# Oracle SQL: issue with age calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to segregate my data into the following categories per age: 1-6,6-12,12-18,>18.

The issue I have is when the age calculates as 6, the record is not showing up in any of the category. I expect it should be in 6-12 per my logic below.

To avoid duplicates, I have written my query as:
`1-6: age<=5`
`6-12: age >=6 <=11`
`12-18:age >=12 <=17`
`>18:age >=18`

why am I missing the records that have age 6?

EDIT:
here is my age calculation:
`(date1-DOB)/365.25 >= 6`
`(date1-DOB)/ 365.25 <= 11`

I also tried 1-6 as <6, 6-12 as >6 <12 and 12-18 as >12 <18 but in some cases, age 6 shows up in both 1-6 and 6-12. And 12 in 6-12 and 12-18. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Please post the full query. Also, if this is not pl/sql it should not be tagged as such.

Comment: (do you have a rounding problem here?) so if the logic calculates the age as 5.99 is that <=5 or >=6?  without knowing how you get "Age" i don't know if the factions are the problem.

Comment: If you use a `CASE` expression you only need to define one bound per `WHEN` as it will evaluate them in order and exit after a condition is met.  `CASE WHEN age < 6 THEN '1-5' WHEN age < 12 THEN '6-11' ... END`

Comment: @xQbert : I think I was able to figure this out the moment you mentioned fractions :D I used 5.999 and this solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: skn @Aleksej has a good approach  it's safer than using 5.999 as you could have rouding errors.  better to use the next number and correct >= or < signs

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` where you can expicitly write the conditions to match each range; for example:

```
select x, 
       case
        when x >=  1 and x <  6 then '1-6'
        when x >=  6 and x < 12 then '6-12'
        when x >= 12 and x < 18 then '12-18'
        when x >= 18            then '>18'
        else 'not matched'
       end as range
from ( select level / 2 as x from dual connect by level < 20 )
```

You can do the same thing in different ways, but I believe this is one of the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

You have  ..not covered range in always range eg:

```
1-6:  age <6          not <=5 and 
6-12: age >=6 <=12    not age >=6 <=11  
12-18:age >=12 <=18   not >=12 <=17 
>18:age >=18
```

Comment: But when I do that, records with age 6 are getting counted in both 1-6 and 6-12. how do I avoid this?

Comment: Update you question and show the exact code  .. because ..the fact that age 6 is counted two time with my suggestion is strange ....